# File Sytem in Linux vs Windows

Tags: windows, unix, filesystems

I created a webpage and saved it in ubuntu with the path as "home\Software\file.html". Then I used wine to download Safari browser and when I opened the page through safari's open file window, the address of file on the search bar is displayed as "C:/users/vidhan/MyDocuments/Software/file.html". Why is this happening?

Edit:I understand that Wine is creating windows environment in the user space. I wanted to know the kind of mapping between home\Software\file.html in Ubuntu and C:/users/vidhan/MyDocuments/Software/file.html in Windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading this Will Answer Your Question [WINE Software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wine_%28software%29) Understand what WINE is and what it does,  but.. in short,  to answer you question, it's happening because WINE is doing it.   Hope that answers your question

Comment: I understand that Wine is creating windows environment in the user space. I wanted to know the kind of mapping between home\Software\file.html in Ubuntu and C:/users/vidhan/MyDocuments/Software/file.html in Windows

Comment: Your original Question was "Why is this happening", and I have told you that it's happening as a Result of Wine,  you've now changed the Question to "I want to know the type of mapping"  You should start another thread and Word the Question correctly, because this would be deemed going off topic, Incidentally, Define what you mean by Mapping Type,  I'm interested to know Your definition of Mapping,  but, really, You should start another thread as this question is deemed to be answered. Hope that helps